# Batch Replace and add 1 to a number between specific text in an xml file

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file, cmd, find-replace

Ok i'm trying to write a batch to "grab" a serial number for the user. The serial number comes from another system and we have to periodically manually input a serial number.  I would like the user to run the batch file which would add 1 and replace the old number and then echo "Your serial number is ##" where ## is the new number. I'm pretty sure i can work out the Echo part and the writing to a temp file and overwriting the old file but its the middle part that im struggling with. 
The xml file is that is being edited is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BatchSettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SerialFormat>{0:yyMMdd}{1:00}</SerialFormat>
  <LastSerialDate>2020-05-27T00:00:00-05:00</LastSerialDate>
  <LastSerialNumber>10</LastSerialNumber>
</BatchSettings>
```

the number i need to change is the ## between "lastserialnumber" `<LastSerialNumber>10</LastSerialNumber>`. 
I've tried a few different approaches and this first one is close but definitely no cigar.

```
@echo off
set /a "replace=10"
set /a "replaced=replace+1"

set "source=Test.txt"
set "target=Test2.txt"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %source%') do (
      set "line=%%b"
      if defined line set "line=!line:%replace%=%replaced%!"
      echo(!line!
   )
) > %target%
endlocal
```

The problem with that one is the number won't always be "10" and I also don't want to replace all the other instances of "10" in the file.

I've also tried

```
@Echo Off
Set "SrcFile=Test.txt"
Set "OutFile=Test2.txt"

@echo off 
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion 

    (for /f "delims=" %%a in (%SrcFile%
    ) do for /f "tokens=2 delims=1234567890 " %%b in ("%%~a"
    ) do if not "%%b"==":"  (
        echo(%%~a
    ) else for /f "tokens=1 delims=  <LastSerialNumber>:" %%c in ("%%~a"
    ) do (
        set /a "n=%%c+1"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo(<LastSerialNumber>!n!:
        endlocal
    )) > %OutFile%
```

but that doesn't increment the number and cuts off the remaining text.
and this one is just a hot mess that doesn't work at all.

```
@Echo Off
Set "SrcFile=Test.txt"
Set "OutFile=Test2.txt"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I /L "<LastSerialNumber>" %SrcFile%') do (
   set "line=%%a
   set "line=!line:*<LastSerialNumber>=!"
   for /F "delims=<" %%b in ("!line!") do echo %%b+1
)) > %oldnumber%

set "newnumber=%oldnumber%+1"

(
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %SrcFile%') do (
      set "line=%%b"
      if defined line set "line=!line:%oldnumber%=%newnumber%!"
        echo(!line!
   )
) > %OutFile%
endlocal
```

Comment: For manipulating XML data I recommend to use a language that natively supports it, like [tag:powershell] or [tag:javascript], for instance; a [tag:batch-file] treats it just as normal text, so it is prone to corrupting it. Anyway, does `<LastSerialNumber>10</LastSerialNumber>` always occur like shown in a single separate line?

Comment: The "lastserialnumber" line always occurs like shown, just different serial numbers obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first let us take a quick look at your attempts:

1. fails as it searches just for `10` and does not regard the `<LastSerialNumber>` tags at all.
2. fails because you try to define a string for the `delims=` option of `for /F` although it actually defines a set of characters.
3. fails because you try to redirect (`>`) into a variable, which cannot work, you can only redirect to files. Furthermore, you attempt to do arithmetics (`+1`) but this only works when using `set /A`. And the last section has got the same problem as approach 1.

---

Here is a way you could do it:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1" & rem // (input file; `%~1` is the first argument)
set "_TAG=<LastSerialNumber>" & rem // (opening tag)

rem // Loop over all (non-empty) lines of the input file:
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%_FILE%") do (
    rem // Store current line string:
    set "LINE=%%L"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid troubles with `!`:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Split off opening tag from line string:
    set "TEST=!LINE:*%_TAG%=!"
    rem // Check whether opening tag has been found:
    if not "!TEST!"=="!LINE!" (
        rem // Opening tag found, hence split off closing tag:
        for /F "tokens=1* eol=< delims=< " %%S in ("!TEST!") do (
            rem // Get extracted number and increment it:
            set /A "NUM=%%S+1"
            rem // Return rebuild line with incremented number:
            echo(  !_TAG!!NUM!^<%%T
        )
    ) else (
        rem // Opening tag not found, hence return original line:
        echo(!LINE!
    )
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Given the batch file is called `inc-serial.bat`, call it with the input XML file as a command line argument (say `test.xml` in the current directory):

```cmd
inc-serial.bat "test.xml"
```

To write the output to another file use redirection (`>`):

```cmd
inc-serial.bat "test.xml" > "test_NEW.xml"
```

Comment: This works great and i can call it with another batchfile which works, but how would i edit this code to slip it into a batch file.  I would rather not have to have 2 separate batch files clogging up the directory and having to remember if i ever move them if i don't have to. I've tried replacing the %~1 with the original file name and adding an output file variable or directly redirecting (i.e. > "Test2.xml")  but no matter where i put it it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, replace `%~1` with the path to the input file (if you just put a pure file name, it refers to the current working directory; if you prefix it with `%~dp0`, it refers to the parent directory of the script). To define an output file (say by `set "_OUTF=..."` in the same manner), enclose the whole `for /F` loop block in another pair of parentheses and append `> "%_OUTF%"` at the closing `)`...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i've finally got the code to work how i need. Just have to set directories which i've left off here for obvious reasons.  Thank you very much to aschipfl for the help.
This code indexes the serial number by one, writes to temp file, then writes back and deletes temp file. Then displays the new serial number.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=BatchTest.xml" & rem // (input file; `%~1` is the first argument)
set "_TAG=<LastSerialNumber>" & rem // (opening tag)

rem // Loop over all (non-empty) lines of the input file:
(for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%_FILE%") do (
    rem // Store current line string:
    set "LINE=%%L"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid troubles with `!`:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Split off opening tag from line string:
    set "TEST=!LINE:*%_TAG%=!"
    rem // Check whether opening tag has been found:
    if not "!TEST!"=="!LINE!" (
        rem // Opening tag found, hence split off closing tag:
        for /F "tokens=1* eol=< delims=< " %%S in ("!TEST!") do (
            rem // Get extracted number and increment it:
            set /A "NUM=%%S+1"
        rem // Return rebuild line with incremented number:
            echo(  !_TAG!!NUM!^<%%T
        )
    ) else (
        rem // Opening tag not found, hence return original line:
        echo(!LINE!
    )
    endlocal
))>BatchTestTmp.xml 


copy /v /y "BatchTestTmp.xml" "BatchTest.xml" & cls

del "BatchTestTmp.xml"

set "LINE=4"
(for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`more +%LINE% BatchTest.xml`) DO (
set result=%%a
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Your Serial Number is !result:~20,2!
pause 
goto :leave
))
:leave
endlocal

exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

As impressive as it's to see that good old Batch can still solve this issue, it's not designed with support for XML in mind. So I would recommend a tool that natively supports XML, like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel).

The "ECHO part" is easy:

```
xidel -s input.xml -e "concat('Your serial number is ',//LastSerialNumber,' where ',//LastSerialNumber + 1, is the new number')"
xidel -s input.xml -e "x'Your serial number is {//LastSerialNumber} where {//LastSerialNumber + 1} is the new number'"
Your serial number is 10 where 11 is the new number
```

The editing:

```
xidel -s input.xml -e "x:replace-nodes(//LastSerialNumber/text(),function($x){$x + 1})" --output-format=xml --output-declaration="<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BatchSettings xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SerialFormat>{0:yyMMdd}{1:00}</SerialFormat>
  <LastSerialDate>2020-05-27T00:00:00-05:00</LastSerialDate>
  <LastSerialNumber>11</LastSerialNumber>
</BatchSettings>
```

To replace the input-file, simply add `--in-place`:

```
xidel -s --in-place input.xml ...
```

To write the output to another file, you could of course redirect the output to one...

```
xidel -s input.xml ... > input_edit.xml
```

...or you can use [`file:write()`](http://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#file-write):

```
xidel -s input.xml -e "file:write('input_edit.xml',x:replace-nodes(//LastSerialNumber/text(),function($x){$x + 1}),{'omit-xml-declaration':false()})"
```

However, `file:write()` in this case puts out `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. If you want the original declaration (without the "encoding" bit), then you have to use `file:write-text()` and add it manually. This combined with the "ECHO part":

```
xidel -s input.xml -e "x'Your serial number is {//LastSerialNumber} where {//LastSerialNumber + 1} is the new number'" -e "file:write-text('input_edit.xml',('<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>',serialize(x:replace-nodes(//LastSerialNumber/text(),function($x){$x + 1}))))"
Your serial number is 10 where 11 is the new number
```

The first extraction query prints the message string. The second writes the output to *'input_edit.txt'*.

The last Xidel command prettified (with the necessary escape-characters):

```
xidel -s input.xml ^
-e "x'Your serial number is {//LastSerialNumber} where {//LastSerialNumber + 1} is the new number'" ^
-e ^"^
  file:write-text(^
    'input_edit.xml',^
    (^
      '^<?xml version=\"1.0\"?^>',^
      serialize(x:replace-nodes(//LastSerialNumber/text(),function($x){$x + 1}))^
    )^
  )^
"
```