# Increment attribute value in an XML file using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, taleo

I am trying to edit an xml file and increment an attribute value called 'pageindex'.

The data in the xml file looks like this

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<quer:query productCode="RC1700" model="http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01" projectedClass="Candidate" locale="en" alias="MainQuery" mode="T-XML" largegraph="true"
preventDuplicates="false" attributes="pageindex=1,pagingsize=350" 
xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
<quer:subQueries/><quer:projections>
<quer:projection><quer:field path="Number"/>
</quer:projection><quer:projection><quer:field path="FirstName"/>
```

This is the batch script I created but the value '1' is not getting incremented.

```
    @echo off
    setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
    
    rem // Define constants here:
    set "_FILE=pagexml" & rem // (input file; `%~1` is the first argument)
    set "_INI=<quer:query productCode="RC1700" model="http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01" projectedClass="Candidate" locale="en" alias="MainQuery" mode="T-XML" largegraph="true" preventDuplicates="false" attributes=" &
    set "_TAG=pageindex=" & rem // (opening tag)
    
    rem // Loop over all (non-empty) lines of the input file:
    (for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%_FILE%") do (
        rem // Store current line string:
        set "LINE=%%L"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid troubles with `!`:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Split off opening tag from line string:
        set "TEST=!LINE:*%_TAG%=!"
        rem // Check whether opening tag has been found:
        if not "!TEST!"=="!LINE!" (
            rem // Opening tag found, hence split off closing tag:
            for /F "tokens=1* eol=, delims=, " %%S in ("!TEST!") do (
                rem // Get extracted number and increment it:
                set /A "NUM=%%S+1"
            rem // Return rebuild line with incremented number:
                echo( !_INI!!_TAG!!NUM!^,%%T
            )
        ) else (
            rem // Opening tag not found, hence return original line:
            echo(!LINE!
        )
        endlocal
    ))>pageTmp.xml 
    
    
    copy /v /y "pageTmp.xml" "page.xml"

del "pageTmp.xml"
```

This is the output I get when I run the bat. You can see that the attribute 'pageindex' does not return any value.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<quer:query productCode="RC1700" model="http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01" projectedClass="Candidate" locale="en" alias="MainQuery" mode="T-XML" largegraph="true"
preventDuplicates="false" attributes="pageindex=,pagingsize=350" 
xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
<quer:subQueries/><quer:projections>
<quer:projection><quer:field path="Number"/>
</quer:projection><quer:projection><quer:field path="FirstName"/>
```

How do I fix this? Also this is my first time working with a batch script!

Comment: I have seen this code [somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62074885)… ;-) Anyway, to edit XML data you should use a language that natively supports it (like PowerShell, VBScript, JavaScript, for example)…

Comment: It does not appear that the given text is considered a valid XML file. Try with PowerShell using `[xml](Get-Content -Path 'C:\src\t\quer.xml')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is your search string `_TAG=pageindex=`.
When using it in `set "TEST=!LINE:*%_TAG%=!"`, this results to

```
==1,pagingsize=350"
```

The equal sign is doubled, because the serach expression can't contain an equal sign, the equal sign is always used to split the search and replace part.
You search for `pageindex` and replace it with `=`

Therefore `%%S` contains `==1` and `set /a NUM===1+1` fails

You can solve it by changing `delims=,`  to `delims=,=`  in

```
for /F "tokens=1* eol=, delims=,= " %%S in ("!TEST!") do (
```